# Django Multiselectfield works locally but not on server

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I've installed `multiselectfield` on my machine and it works well. I can choose multiple items thanks to multiple checkboxes in admin:
[image]

Then I had to copy/paste all the files of the project to my VPS using Filezilla. So I have the exact same code and the exact same files locally and remotely. The site works well remotely (the VPS django admin page too).

However on the server's django admin page, the `multiselectfield` widget shows a simple text field instead of an actual list of checkboxes, plus it says `Enter a list of values.` when I try to validate the form.
[image]
So, how is it, that with the same code at two different places, the multiselectfield acts differently and how to I fix this ?

my field looks like this in the model:

```
ram_list = tuple((ram.ref, ram.name) for ram in RAM.objects.all())
ram = MultiSelectField(choices=ram_list)
```

Comment: Please check your virtual environment, maybe when you copy the necessary packages is missing.

Comment: could you elaborate ? what is your definition of checking my venv, and how do i check

Comment: I mean sometimes when I copy a project to another computer, I need install again necessary packages, example like `django-multiselectfield`

Comment: i've installed all necessary packages on both sides, that's why i find it a strange issue...